# finding first day of the month in python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to find the first day of the month in python with one condition: if my current date passed the 25th of the month, then the first date variable will hold the first date of the next month instead of the current month. I'm doing the following:

```
import datetime 
todayDate = datetime.date.today()
if (todayDate - todayDate.replace(day=1)).days > 25:
    x= todayDate + datetime.timedelta(30)
    x.replace(day=1)
    print x
else:
    print todayDate.replace(day=1)
```

is there a cleaner way for doing this?

Comment: Btw, your test `todayDate - todayDate.replace(day=1)).days > 25` only becomes true on the 27th, not the 26th. Do you want to do what you say in words, or what you say in code?

Comment: And it seems to me that you might run into problems in the late days of February.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is a pithy solution.

```
import datetime 

todayDate = datetime.date.today()
if todayDate.day > 25:
    todayDate += datetime.timedelta(7)
print todayDate.replace(day=1)
```

One thing to note with the original code example is that using `timedelta(30)` **will cause troubl**e if you are testing the last day of January. That is why I am using a 7-day delta.

Comment: You are correct @J.F.Sebastian! That is even pithier, so I made your suggested change.

Answer (score 338):

Can be done on the same line using [`date.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace):

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.today().replace(day=1)
```

Comment: This does not actually solve the posted question. Note the constraint "if my current date passed the 25th of the month then the first date variable will hold the first date of the next month "

Comment: But it does solve the question people coming here via a search engine have :)

Comment: Here's the first day of the previous month as well `print( ((datetime.datetime.today().replace(day=1)) - datetime.timedelta(days=30)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') )`

Comment: @ffghfgh don't think that will always work.. what if "today" is March 1st, going back 30 days will go past Feb in January.

Comment: First day of the previous month improved: now = datetime.datetime.utcnow();
start = now.replace(month=now.month-1).replace(day=1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: @RayHulha your code doesn't work when it's January because `.replace(month=0)` raises a `ValueError`. @ffghfgh's code returns the 2nd day for months whose previous month doesn't have 30 days, which is most of them so I guess your code *is* strictly speaking an improvement, giving the wrong answer ~1/12 of the time is better than giving the wrong answer ~8/12 of the time.

Comment: Improved version: `start = (now.replace(day=1)-datetime.timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 21):

```
from datetime import datetime

date_today = datetime.now()
month_first_day = date_today.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
print(month_first_day)
```

Comment: this is a good solution for getting the timestamp of first day of the month, in cases you need to query the current month or so.

Answer (score 15):

Use [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/).

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

today = date.today()
first_day = today.replace(day=1)
if today.day > 25:
    print(first_day + relativedelta(months=1))
else:
    print(first_day)
```

Comment: your answer also has how to find the last day, thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Use [arrow](https://github.com/arrow-py/arrow).

```
import arrow
arrow.utcnow().span('month')[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be an alternative to Gustavo Eduardo Belduma's answer:

```
import datetime 
first_day_of_the_month = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
```

Comment: I did not want to edit anything in his answer since I didn't check if his solution is correct, this is just an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

I found a clean way to do this is to create a datetime object using the month and year attributes of todayDate, with days set to 1 i.e.

```
import datetime 
todayDate = datetime.date.today()

firstOfMon = datetime.date(todayDate.year, todayDate.month, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, first set a datetime to the start of the current month.

Second test if current date day > 25 and get a true/false on that. If True then add add one month to the start of month datetime object. If false then use the datetime object with the value set to the beginning of the month.

```
import datetime 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

todayDate = datetime.date.today()
resultDate = todayDate.replace(day=1)

if ((todayDate - resultDate).days > 25):
    resultDate = resultDate + relativedelta(months=1)

print resultDate
```

Answer (score 2):

The **arrow** module will steer you around and away from subtle mistakes, and it's easier to use that older products.

```
import arrow

def cleanWay(oneDate):
    if currentDate.date().day > 25:
        return currentDate.replace(months=+1,day=1)
    else:
        return currentDate.replace(day=1)


currentDate = arrow.get('25-Feb-2017', 'DD-MMM-YYYY')
print (currentDate.format('DD-MMM-YYYY'), cleanWay(currentDate).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'))

currentDate = arrow.get('28-Feb-2017', 'DD-MMM-YYYY')
print (currentDate.format('DD-MMM-YYYY'), cleanWay(currentDate).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'))
```

In this case there is no need for you to consider the varying lengths of months, for instance. Here's the output from this script.

```
25-Feb-2017 01-Feb-2017
28-Feb-2017 01-Mar-2017
```

Comment: it's better to use Arrow.shift `currentDate.shift(months=+1).replace(day=1)` instead replace to avoid getting passed days.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dateutil.rrule](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html%20dateutil.rrule):

```
In [1]: from dateutil.rrule import *

In [2]: rrule(DAILY, bymonthday=1)[0].date()
Out[2]: datetime.date(2018, 10, 1)

In [3]: rrule(DAILY, bymonthday=1)[1].date()
Out[3]: datetime.date(2018, 11, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
last_month=(datetime.now().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to find the first and last day of the current month:

```
def find_current_month_last_day(today: datetime) -> datetime:
    if today.month == 2:
        return today.replace(day=28)

    if today.month in [4, 6, 9, 11]:
        return today.replace(day=30)

    return today.replace(day=31)


def current_month_first_and_last_days() -> tuple:
    today = datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    first_date = today.replace(day=1)
    last_date = find_current_month_last_day(today)
    return first_date, last_date
```

Answer (score 0):

First day of next month:

`from datetime import datetime`

```
class SomeClassName(models.Model):
    if datetime.now().month == 12:
        new_start_month = 1
    else:
        new_start_month = datetime.now().month + 1
```

Then we replace the month and the day

```
    start_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today().replace(month=new_start_month, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Jouberto's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70258573/1583913) and [@akx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx)'s answers (elsewhere), oneliners without any dependencies:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo("UTC"))
this_month = now.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
next_month = (this_month.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)).replace(day=1)
last_month = (this_month.replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (basically) one-line solution I came up with to calculate your `target_date` that uses standard modules, and no if/branching logic:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

target_date = ((date.today() - timedelta(25)).replace(day=1) + timedelta(31)).replace(day=1)

print(target_date)
```

This solution might look overly wordy, but bear in mind that there's no branching logic involved.  If you prefer to have more lines to help with readability, you can use this:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

d = date.today()
d -= timedelta(25)
d = d.replace(day=1)
d += timedelta(31)
d = d.replace(day=1)

print(d)
```

Explanation:

- By subtracting `timedelta(25)` we rewind the date so that dates from 1 to 25 cross a month boundary (to the previous month).  (The dates from 26 to 31 don't cross over and therefore get to keep their month values, setting them apart from the other dates.)
- The first `.replace(day=1)` rewinds the date to the first of that month.  (This *would* be the answer you're looking for, but it's a month too early.)
- By adding `timedelta(31)`, we jump forward to the next month.

Now, not all months have 31 days, so we may be adjusting the date to the 1st or 2nd, or even the 3rd or 4th of the month (due to uneven month lengths).  So how do we account for these differences?  That's simple to do:

- The second `.replace(day=1)` rewinds the date back to the first of the month, regardless of whether the previous date was on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, or 4th of the month.  This new date is exactly what you're looking for.

Use whichever of the two solutions above you prefer.  Neither one uses branching logic, which means that every starting date goes through the exact same steps to arrive at the final date.

(And as a bonus for the code's maintainers, if you ever want to change the day value of 25 to some other value (from 2 to 28), only the one value in the code needs to change.)

Answer (score -2):

```
firstday_currentMonth_start = datetime.today().replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

previousday_currentMonth_end = datetime.today().replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999) - timedelta(days=1)

lastday_lastmonth = firstday_currentMonth_start.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999) - timedelta(days=1)

firstday_lastmonth = lastday_lastmonth.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

print(firstday_lastmonth)

print(lastday_lastmonth)

print(firstday_currentMonth_start)

print(previousday_currentMonth_end)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35079339)