# how to get number of days in month based on date string input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to automate a code.  I would like to have the code pull data starting at the beginning of the month to end of the previous day. Currently I am using the following command to get the enddate:

```
dateEnd = pd.to_datetime('today')
```

How do tell the code, based on what today is to go back to the beginning of the month?  AND, how do I tell the code if its the first of the month to return the previous months data?

For a bonus, once I have the start and end date, how do return find the number of days in the month?  I have tried this command, but it does not want to work on a single date.

```
startTime_date.dt.daysinmonth
```

Comment: Re: "for a bonus", SO isn't a quiz. Can you ask one *specific* question and show us your latest attempts?

Comment: Here is how to find the first day of the month: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396329/finding-first-day-of-the-month-in-python

Comment: Here is how to find the last day of the month: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python

Comment: You can use an "if" statement to go to the previous month if today is the first day of the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the wanted dates:

```
import datetime

end = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)
start = end.replace(day=1)
daysInMonth = (datetime.date(start.year, start.month + 1, 1) - datetime.timedelta(1)).day

start
#2018-10-01

end
#2018-10-09

daysInMonth
#31
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I can't tell you how much this helped.  PLUS! the Bonus!!  Thank you.

Comment: What is the "replace" command doing?  I see. its replacing the day with 1.  thanks again