# Django model datefield with YYYY-MM instead YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to have a model YYYY_MM which stores

- 2022-01
- 2022-02
- etc

I thought the best method would be to use the DateField but it looks like that YYYY-MM-DD is enforced?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just store YYYY-MM-DD and display YYYY_MM to the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

`DateField` stores a python date. But 2022-01 is not a date it is a month.

To solve a similar problem before, I have used the convention of storing the first day of a certain time period. In my case this was first day of week to store weeks, but it should be the same thing.

Check out this answer for an idea of how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266909/15038439

Answer (score 0):

I have used this `MonthDateField` instead of the normal `DateField`. It still saves a proper date in the database (with the first of the month), but serializers and initializing using a string allows the use of a date formatted in `YYYY-MM`.

It also inherits from `DateField` which means that using `date`-format will also work.

```py
class MonthDateField(models.DateField):
    """Month date field. Assumes that the incoming value is of the form 'YYYY-MM'."""

    def to_python(self, value):
        """Try to parse the incoming value and keep only the month part."""
        if isinstance(value, str):
            try:
                year, month = map(int, value.split("-"))
                return super().to_python(f"{year}-{month:02d}-01")
            except (ValueError, IndexError) as err:
                raise ValidationError("Invalid date format. Use 'YYYY-MM'.") from err
        return super().to_python(value)
```